# Multiple file uploads in Multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, multer

I am trying to upload 3 files in my rest api in express using multer, but only first file is getting uploaded. I have configured correctly, but why am I facing the bug. Please help...

```
//route.js
  router.patch(
    protect,
    restrictToRole('admin'),
    uploadtourPhotos,
    resizeTourPhotos,
    updateTour,
  )

//controller.js
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();

const multerFileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (file.mimetype.startsWith('image')) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(new AppError(400, `Uploaded file is not an image.`), false);
  }
};

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter: multerFileFilter,
});

exports.uploadtourPhotos = upload.fields([
  { name: 'coverImage', maxCount: 1 },
  { name: 'image', maxCount: 2 },
]);

exports.resizeTourPhotos = handleAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.files);
  console.log(req.body);

  next();
});
```

this is how I am uploading the files from postman:
[image]

```
log:
 App running on PORT: 8000 
✔ connected to database ⛁
[Object: null prototype] {
  coverImage: [
    {
      fieldname: 'coverImage',
      originalname: 'garbage collection js.png',
      encoding: '7bit',
      mimetype: 'image/png',
      buffer: <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 06 40 00 00 03 48 08 06 00 00 00 9f 67 23 6d 00 00 00 09 70 48 59 73 00 00 0e c4 00 00 0e c4 01 ... 186726 more bytes>,
      size: 186776
    }
  ]
}
[Object: null prototype] { image: [ '', '' ] }
```

Comment: You have provided field name as `image` in multer ( `{ name: 'image', maxCount: 2 }` ) but in your rest client you have provided `images` instead of `image`

Comment: @bogdanoff sorry for confusion, it was previous image, now I am using image as key in the form data, but still only first key is getting uploaded.

Comment: I just tried myself and its working as intended, seems its problem with other code that you haven't shared here.  Here is [my code](https://pastebin.com/jM50i1c9) try it out.

Comment: @bogdanoff Thanks so much for helping out, I was trying in postman extension inside vs code where it was not working. I tried in the Postman app and it worked fine. Maybe its the issue of vs code extension. THanks again for your concern.

Answer (score 1):

made some changes and it works fine now. i think it was either due to bodyParser.json() or for using *export.* in your router.patch

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require('multer');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const handleAsync = (fn) => (req, res, next) =>
    Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next)).catch(next);

const protect = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Protect middleware');
    next();
};

const restrictToRole = (role) => (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(`Restrict to ${role} middleware`);
    next();
};

const storage = multer.memoryStorage();

const multerFileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if (file.mimetype.startsWith('image')) {
        cb(null, true);
    } else {
        cb(new Error('Uploaded file is not an image.'), false);
    }
};

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: multerFileFilter,
});

router.use(bodyParser.json());

exports.uploadtourPhotos = upload.fields([
    { name: 'coverImage', maxCount: 1 },
    { name: 'image', maxCount: 2 },
]);

exports.resizeTourPhotos = handleAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.files);
    console.log(req.body);

    next();
});

router.patch(
    '/',
    protect,
    restrictToRole('admin'),
    exports.uploadtourPhotos,
    exports.resizeTourPhotos, 
);

module.exports = router;
```